# Reset stack from nested navigator in react navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a screen nested in a navigator which is inside a navigator.

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
AuthLoading,
MainNavigator,
AuthNavigator
},
{
initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
});

const AuthNavigator = createStackNavigator({
VerificationNavigator,
OtpVerificationStack
},
{
initialRouteName: 'VerificationNavigator',
header: null,
headerMode: 'none'
});
```

AppNavigator loads AuthNavigator first, then from VerificationNavigator(second screen) I navigate to OtpVerificationStack using navigation props.

```
const OtpVerificationStack = createSwitchNavigator({
OTPLoading,
SignupNavigator,
MainNavigator
},
{ 
initialRouteName: 'OTPLoading',
});
```

In OtpVerificationStack the flow  SignupNavigator loads first.

```
const SignupNavigator = createStackNavigator({
FirstName,
LastName,
Email
},
{
header: null,
headerMode: 'none'
});
```

The Screen FirstName consists of a google login, after successful login I want to go to MainNavigator or it's screen 'Home'.
I tried

```
  const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: OtpVerificationStack,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })
  ]
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

But this does not seem to work. It does nothing!

**EDIT:** I tried setting token in asyncstorage and in the OTPLoadingscreen checked for a token. So in essence, I had to reset it back to OTPVerificationStack which I could do by keeping key: null but I don't know if that is a good method to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this kind of issue and solved by this flow.

You can reset stacknavigator, when you are in the flow.

Stack1:

screen1

screen2

screen3...

Flow screen1->screen2->screen3 (Now if you want to reset it will work).

When you want to reset stack1 and navigate to stack2 initial screen, try the following:

```
navigateToStack(stackName,routeName,params){
        const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: stackName,
            action: NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: routeName,
                params: params,
            })
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
    }
```

You just provide stackname,screen routename correctly.It will automatically go to home.

```
this.navigateToStack(MainTab,home,{item:item}):
```